# Updating AccountShare - syntax issue that I can't find

Tags: apex

Can someone tell me what I am typing wrong. It must be staring me in the face but I am not seeing it.

```
public class accountsharefix {

        list<AccountShare> accshare = new list<AccountShare>(
            [Select ID,AccountAccessLevel,UserOrGroupId
             FROM AccountShare
             WHERE RowCause = 'Team'
             AND UserOrGroupID != '00530000000n6yoAAA'
             AND AccountAccessLevel = 'Read']);

        for(AccountShare as:accshare){
            as.AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit';
        }

        Update accshare;

}
```

Error from Dev console:

```
expecting an equals sign, found 'as'
```

Comment: 1. Don't hard-code your ids. 2. You can see all `Apex` reserved keywords [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. "as" is a reserved word. Had to use another variable. Dummy on me.